# Tic-Tac-Toe autoplay does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic-tac-toe game, the functions works perfectly for the user turn, but when it comes for the computer turn to play, the functions break down and give unexpected result like playing two times, skip the turn and so.

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my codes, and help me to fix this issue?

```js
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const table = document.getElementById('table');
places = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 'eight', "nine"];
let move = 0;
start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    user();
});


function user(){
    table.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let pos = event.target;
        let Id = event.target.id;
        if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){
            pos.innerHTML = "X";
            move += 1;
            places.splice(places.indexOf(Id), 1 );
        }
        if (move > 8){
            gameOver();
        } 
        if (move <= 8){
            computer();
        }
    });
}

function gameOver(){
    console.log("Game Over");
}

function computer(){
    let index = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
    let pos = document.getElementById(index);
    if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){
        pos.innerHTML = "O";
        move += 1;
        places.splice(places.indexOf(pos), 1 );
    }
    if (move > 8){
        gameOver();
    } 
    if (move <= 8) {
        user();
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col text-center">
    <table class="table text-center">
        <tbody id="table">
            <tr>
                <td id="one">1</td>
                <td id="two">2</td>
                <td id="three">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="four">4</td>
                <td id="five">5</td>
                <td id="six">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="seven">7</td>
                <td id="eight">8</td>
                <td id="nine">9</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="start">Start Game</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're adding a `click` event to your table every time it's the computer turn. You should rethink your approach. The easiest thing to do is not to call `user` when the computer's turn ends and move the event declaration outside the `user` function.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't understand what you mean, can you explain more, I will be so thankful if you edit the codes for me.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to rephrase my original answer:
When it is the computers turn, you are executing this code

```
function computer(){
    let index = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
    let pos = document.getElementById(index);
    if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){
        pos.innerHTML = "O";
        move += 1;
        places.splice(places.indexOf(pos), 1 );
    }
    if (move > 8){
        gameOver();
    } 
    if (move <= 8) {
        user();
    }
```

}

What happens if `if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){` returns false? (that is the field is already occupied), your code just keeps executing as if the computer already made a move handing over the turn to the user.

So my suggestion is that you need to ensure that the computer actually makes a move, one way is to add a found variable that is initialized to false and first set to true when a computer move is actually found and made.

This can be done by modifying your method to something like:

```
function computer(){
   let foundEmptyField=false;
   while(foundEmptyField===false) 
   {
     let index = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
     let pos = document.getElementById(index);
     if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){
        pos.innerHTML = "O";
        move += 1;
        places.splice(places.indexOf(pos), 1 );
        foundEmptyField = true;
     }
     if(foundEmptyField===true) {
        if (move > 8){
           gameOver();
        } 
        if (move <= 8) {
           user();
        }
     }
   }
}
```

If you look at your code, you actually haves the exact same problem in your user() code

Comment: This is just a raw suggestion, you need to adjust the code, i.e recalculate index and pos again
(I just modified the answer it a bit, but I havn't tested it ....)

Answer (score 0):

**Issue explained:**
You have created an event listener that takes place each time the user makes a click

```
    start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    user();
});
```

What you failed to do, is identify who's turn it is, therefore the user could potentially double click or even click on a played tile or even click on the computers turn and the code would not turn the user away but accept the move as the players turn.

I have therefore added to the user function

```
        }else{
      return;
    }
```

which will ignore the turn played, if the tile clicked on has been played already as denoted by an X

I have also added to the computer function a call to retry a move, if the computer randomly generates a played tile number, so that it doesnt hand back to the player, but rather tries again.

```
}else{
  computer();
}
```

Finally I streamlined your code a bit as you had repeated code which could be turned into a function with a variable passed to it.

```
    function gameStateCheck(stTurn){
    if (move > 8){
        gameOver();
    } 
    if (move <= 8) {
        if (stTurn == "user"){
          user();
         }else{
          computer();
         }
    }
}
```

**Alternative Solution:**
This solution entirely - re-writes your code, but its one that is working and doesnt get caught up in function call loops as the CPU is taught to know what moves are valid.

```js
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const table = document.getElementById('table');
places = [];
start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    places = [];    // reset the array of available tiles to play
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){ // re populate available tiles 0-8
      places.push (i);
    }
    
    // run a loop to clear the previous game cell markers (O or X);
    for (x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++){
        for (i = 0; i < table.rows[x].cells.length; i++){
          table.rows[x].cells[i].innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
    // Mark the users move 
   user();
});


function user(){
    table.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        // get the ID of the played tile
        let Id = parseInt(event.target.id);   
         
         // locate the index number in the array that contains the ID
        let PlayedTile = places.indexOf(Id); 
        
        if (PlayedTile > -1){
          // if PlayerTile is NOT -1, it means it exists in the array
          // lets remove it from the available tiles to play array
          places.splice(places.indexOf(Id), 1 );
          
        }else{
          // Ok so this user has already played this tile or the CPU has
          // Therefore we exit the function and nothing changes on the screen
          
          // Recommendation: add some code to notify your user this move has been played
          return;
        }
        
        // Ok so if we havent exited the function above due to having played the tile
        // we can now update the cell with an "X"
        event.target.innerHTML = "X";
        
        // we now check to see if there are any further moves available (by checking the length
        // of the places array, if it is 0 we declare game over)
        
        if (places.length == 0){
            gameover();
            return;
        }else{
        // otherwise we pass control to the CPU
        computer();
        }
    });
}

function computer(){
    // we know how many moves are available by the length of the array
    // so lets choose 1 random box ID number
    let cpuMove = Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length);
    
    // now lets get the value of that array index, as this value will be the table cell ID
    let cpuPlayedTileId = places[cpuMove];
    
    // now lets grab the cell element by its ID
    let pos = document.getElementById(cpuPlayedTileId);
    
    // Update the cell with an "O" marker
    // NOTE the CPU cannot physically choose an invalid move as the CPU knows the available moves
    pos.innerHTML = "O";
    
    // As it is a valid move, lets remove it from the array for the player.
    places.splice(places.indexOf(cpuPlayedTileId), 1 );
    
    // check if the game is now over
    if (places.length == 0){
        gameover();
        return;
    }else{
      user();
    }
}

function gameover(){
 alert("gameover");
  console.log("Game Over");
}
```

```css
#boardGame{
  background: grey;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
}
#boardGame tr td{
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: small;
}
```

```html
<div class="col text-center">
    <table id="boardGame" class="table text-center">
        <tbody id="table">
            <tr>
                <td id="0"></td>
                <td id="1"></td>
                <td id="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="3"></td>
                <td id="4"></td>
                <td id="5"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="6"></td>
                <td id="7"></td>
                <td id="8"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="start">Start Game</button>
</div>
```

**Your code base, fixed**
*Note you could be potentially be caught in an endless loop which will cause an exceeded call error. But I have left the code as close to what you had above.*

**I have coded a error free code above is as I would code it instead**

```js
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const table = document.getElementById('table');
places = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 'eight', "nine"];
let move = 0;
start.addEventListener('click', function(){
    user();
});


function user(){
    table.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        let pos = event.target;
        let Id = event.target.id;
        if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){
            pos.innerHTML = "X";
            move += 1;
            places.splice(places.indexOf(Id), 1 );
        }else{
          return;
        }
  gameStateCheck("CPU");
    });
}

function gameOver(){
    console.log("Game Over");
}

function computer(){
    let index = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
    let pos = document.getElementById(index);
    if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)){
        pos.innerHTML = "O";
        move += 1;
        places.splice(places.indexOf(pos), 1 );
    }else{
      computer();
    }
    gameStateCheck("user");
}

function gameStateCheck(stTurn){
 if (move > 8){
        gameOver();
    } 
    if (move <= 8) {
        if (stTurn == "user"){
          user();
         }else{
          computer();
         }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="col text-center">
    <table class="table text-center">
        <tbody id="table">
            <tr>
                <td id="one">1</td>
                <td id="two">2</td>
                <td id="three">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="four">4</td>
                <td id="five">5</td>
                <td id="six">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="seven">7</td>
                <td id="eight">8</td>
                <td id="nine">9</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="start">Start Game</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it keeps giving me this error ```script.js:32 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
    at computer (script.js:32)
    at computer (script.js:37)
    at computer (script.js:37)
    at computer (script.js:37)```

Comment: All that means is you need to control the number of times it keeps calling the function Computer()

I can re-script your code to be able to make better use of the array so that it can only generate a random number from what is available (as this is very similar to my Battleships game i developed)

Comment: can you explain for me how to do that ?

Comment: Im going to re-write the code so that it only allows a random number to be generated from what is already in the array and nothing more.

Comment: OK, I'm waring for you .

Comment: Try the Alternative solution
Note: I could code who the winner is in your game, but in reality, that would take the fun out of it for you :)

Clicking start game will now reset the board for a 2nd game

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You add event listener each time the user function is called, but that event listener should only be added once. In the computer function you spliced off the the index of pos, which is an HTMLElement, instead you splice of the index of the index var, which is like "one", "two" etc. The user function should not be called from the computer function since it is triggered by the event listener. The test in the computer function is redundant since the computer only chooses from the untouched elements in places. For clearness i introduced an init function for further extension. The following is a running solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var places, move;
        function init() {
            places = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", 'eight', "nine"];
            move = 0;
            table.addEventListener('click', user);
        }

        function user(event) {
            let pos = event.target;
            let Id = event.target.id;
            if (/[1-9]/.test(pos.innerHTML)) {
                pos.innerHTML = "X";
                move += 1;
                places.splice(places.indexOf(Id), 1);
                if (move > 8) {
                    gameOver();
                }
                else {
                    computer();
                }
            }
        }

        function gameOver() {
            console.log("Game Over");
        }

        function computer() {
            let index = places[Math.floor(Math.random() * places.length)];
            let pos = document.getElementById(index);
            pos.innerHTML = "O";
            move += 1;
            places.splice(places.indexOf(index), 1);
            if (move > 8) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col text-center">
        <table class="table text-center">
            <tbody id="table">
                <tr>
                    <td id="one">1</td>
                    <td id="two">2</td>
                    <td id="three">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="four">4</td>
                    <td id="five">5</td>
                    <td id="six">6</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="seven">7</td>
                    <td id="eight">8</td>
                    <td id="nine">9</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="init()" id="start">Start Game</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ayman tarig: Tested with Firefox for Ubuntu/canonical-1.0 and Chrome 71.0.3578.98/Linux. As designed by yourself for the game to run the page must be reloaded and Start Game button pressed.